# TDateTime data type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, tdatetime

I have been using C++ Builder to develop some classes. I have been using the TDateTime data type by including the 'vcl.h'. Is this only unique to C++ Builder?

I ask this because I am now using Microsoft Visual Studio C++ and am getting a 'TDateTime is undefined error'.

How can I use this type in Visual Studio?

Thanks

Comment: `TDateTime` is certainly not part of the standard C++ library.

Comment: How can I add this to my Project?

Comment: I don't know if you can intal it by itself, but would you be interested in open source and/or C++ standard alternatives?

Comment: Yes I would be. Shall I try Bloodshed? Basically, I am wanting to use my C++ Builder code (that uses the TDateTime data type) in another C++ development IDE. My evaluation version runs out tomorrow...

Comment: I have added some suggestions in an answer. Unfortunately, I don't think they provide an easy drop-in replacement, but with a bit of work you can get the functionality you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Borland's Visual Component Library is built around it's own compiler-specific extensions and delphi code.   I very much doubt you will have an easy time getting it to work under any other compiler.

LUckily there are plenty of alternatives.   If you're using Visual C++, then you can use Microsoft's Date/Time libraries: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ahxxcsz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

There are also portable libraries from Boost and QT which should run under any modern C++ compiler

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time.html
- http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/qdatetime.html

Comment: 1) Borland is now Embarcadero 2) I would strongly focus on starting date of a [`TDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TDateTime) data type and if it matches to those you've suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having a look at [boost.datetime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time.html) and, if you have access to C++11 support, the [standard C++ time and time duration utilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) available in the `<chrono>` header. One advantage of using either of these is that they are portable, so you are not bound to a given compiler or development environment.

Comment: The thing is. I have already written hundreds of lines of code, and they use the TDateTime object. I do not want to rewrite everything with a different data type...

Comment: @user1690531 That's the kind of thing you need to expect when migrating vendor-specific code from one compiler/platform to another.  (hence the reason "portable" libraries exist and are generally quite popular).   Rewriting is usually the best option;  the only other (**worse**) alternative is to create your own type called `TDateTime` in visual C++ which takes the TDateTime interface but acts as a wrapper for another date/time library of your choice

Comment: Can I just include the library that C++ Builder uses?

Comment: @user1690531 The best way to answer that question is to try it for yourself.  As I mentioned in my answer - much of the VCL is built around Borland-specific extensions and uses delphi code;  Visual C++ doesn't know anything about those, so doing that may need you to jump through a lot of hoops.

Comment: @user1690531 It is very likely to be a proprietary library, but I can't say for sure. I really suggest rolling out your own date-time code using a portable solution.